# jQuery show/hide only works on first selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a show hide function for my table. The problem is that the jQuery only seems to work for the first selector and no others.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

**jQuery :**

```
jQuery("document").ready(function($) {
    $("#paragraph-div").hide();

    $("#toggle-div").click(function() {
        if ($("#paragraph-div").is(":visible")) {
           $("#paragraph-div").hide();
            $("#toggle-div").val("Less Info");
        } else {
            $("#paragraph-div").show();
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML :**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a id="toggle-div">More Info</a>
            <div id="paragraph-div">
                <p>Hidden text - Toggle more info to show.</p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a id="toggle-div">More Info</a>
            <div id="paragraph-div">
                <p>Hidden text - Toggle more info to show.</p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a id="toggle-div">More Info</a>
            <div id="paragraph-div">
                <p>Hidden text - Toggle more info to show.</p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: A id selector should be **unique**. That is the problem.

Comment: the table is created in a for each loop in php how can I make it work with the same id?

Comment: While you're busy refactoring your code, please consider not naming your `<a>` elements *toggle*-***div***. You'll thank me in a few years.

Comment: Use class or increment id in your foreach loop ;)

Comment: If i change to class will it work?

Comment: @Scott, at first, but then you will hit the problem where your "current" `paragraph-div` becomes relative to clicked `toggle-div`, and the problem where `val()` on `<a>` (and `<div>`) elements does nothing, and sdsqs@#@[€ŋß»< NO CARRIER

Comment: Try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/385/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/84/)**

`id` should be unique in same document, replace the duplicate once by general class, e.g :

```
<a class="toggle-div">
<div class="paragraph-div">
```

Instead of :

```
<a id="toggle-div">
<div id="paragraph-div">
```

Then use class selector `.` in your js instead of id selector :

```
$(".toggle-div")
$(".paragraph-div")
```

Instead of :

```
$("#toggle-div")
$("#paragraph-div")
```

**NOTES :**

- You could use `$(this)` inside event instead of `".toggle-div"`
- You should use `$(this).next(".paragraph-div")` to select the related paragraph with clicked link.
- The `div` tag haven't a `val()` method you should use `text()` instead.

Hope this helps.

---

### Snippet

```js
jQuery("document").ready(function($) {

  $(".paragraph-div").hide();

  $(".toggle-div").click(function() 
                         {
    if ($(this).next(".paragraph-div").is(":visible")) {
      $(this).next(".paragraph-div").hide();
      $(this).text("More Info");
    } else {
      $(this).next(".paragraph-div").show();
      $(this).text("Less Info");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="toggle-div">More Info</a><div class="paragraph-div"><p>Hidden text - Toggle more info to show.</p></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="toggle-div">More Info</a><div class="paragraph-div"><p>Hidden text - Toggle more info to show.</p></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="toggle-div">More Info</a><div class="paragraph-div"><p>Hidden text - Toggle more info to show.</p></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this :

```js
jQuery("document").ready(function($) {
    $(".paragraph-div").hide();
    $(".toggle-div").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $paragraph = $this.next('.paragraph-div');
        if ($paragraph.is(":visible")) {
            $paragraph.hide();
            $this.html("More Info");
        } else {
            $paragraph.show();
            $this.html("Less Info");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class="toggle-div">More Info</a>
            <div class="paragraph-div">
                <p>Hidden text - Toggle more info to show.</p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class="toggle-div">More Info</a>
            <div class="paragraph-div">
                <p>Hidden text - Toggle more info to show.</p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class="toggle-div">More Info</a>
            <div class="paragraph-div">
                <p>Hidden text - Toggle more info to show.</p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6pq9mp4t/1/))